# Sublime Text 2: Building Parameter with LaTeX

Tags: compiling, editors, external-files, build-system

How can I perform a build process of a certain tex file, different from the current one I'm editing with the Sublime Text 2 Editor?

I use the Sublime Text 2 Editor with MikTex and Sumatra PDF. My latex work is built out of a main.tex file and separate chapter tex files which are included in the main. My intention is to start a new build process of the main.tex file independent of the current active tex file I'm editing.

Comment: You can also have a look at makefiles, and custom makes in sublime text 2. Once you learn how to use them, they become very powerful tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) you can specify the `TEX root` parameter in your source code. For example for such tree:

```
book.tex
chapter01/main.tex
chapter01/01.tex
chapter02/main.tex
```

Specifying the `%!TEX root = ../book.tex` (the path is relative) in chapters `.tex` files would allow Sublime Text 2 (and LaTeXTools, same for TeXworks, for example) to compile the `book.tex`, while editing the `chapter01/main.tex`.